# HERE API - Autocomplete Issue

Tags: maps, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am using the HERE API Autocomplete service, but I had a problem. I am looking for a place in Peru, "Jorge Chavez" (Airport) but it does not return the result of the airport but other addresses despite changing the maximum results to 20

In the demo that is in the same documentation does not show me the result [https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoding_suggestions]

In the WEGO search engine, when searching for "Jorge Chavez" if he returns the result of the airport [https://wego.here.com].

Thank you.

Comment: Would be great if you could share the REST that being called, some parameters could be missed in REST which could cause this

Answer (score 0):

Search on [HereWeGo](https://wego.here.com) will find addresses and places including Airports.

Geocoder and Autocomplete are specialized to return addresses only.
An Autocomplete like functionality that also returns places is "Autosuggest". See the [developer portal](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/quick-start-find-text-string.html) for details.

Autosuggest will return what you are looking for:

> title:Jorge Chávez International Airport (jorge chávez airport)

However, the Geocoder offers a search endpoint that can return places of selected categories. One of them is "airports". So using the following search will return the airport you are looking for

```
search.json?categoryids=4581&searchtext=Jorge%20Chavez%20peru
```